# UINavigationController back button title doesn't update dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have a text field in my view controller and I want to display a custom title for the back button. This is to represent changes made in the text field.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Update back button in the nav bar
    updateBackButton()

    // Text field delegation
    nameTextField.delegate = self
    nameTextField.addTarget(self, action: "updateBackButton", forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)
}
func updateBackButton() {
    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(
        title: formHasChanged ? "Cancel" : "Back",
        style: .Done,
        target: nil,
        action: nil
    )
    print(backButton.title)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem = backButton
}
```

This does effect the back button only once, in the `viewDidLoad` method. On subsequent calls to `updateBackButton()` there's no visible change, even though `print(backButton.title)` does print the appropriate output.

What's missing from my approach in order to have a dynamically updated back button title?

## Output from the `updateBackButton()` method's print statement.

```
Optional("Back")
Optional("Cancel")
Optional("Back")
Optional("Cancel")
Optional("Back")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call a `function` as an `action` from any control's target then you'll have to define it as `@IBAction` and use `:` while calling it. Just like

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
// Update back button in the nav bar
//  updateBackButton() // Now you don't need to call it here, I guess..

// Text field delegation
nameTextField.delegate = self
nameTextField.addTarget(self, action: "updateBackButton:",forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)
}

@IBAction func updateBackButton(sender: AnyObject!) {
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(
    title: formHasChanged ? "Cancel" : "Back",
    style: .Done,
    target: nil,
    action: nil
)
print(backButton.title!)
navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem = backButton
}
```

**Update :**

Try changing this line

`navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem = backButton`
with
`navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.leftBarButtonItem = backButton` or simply `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton`

**PS** :  It will not show you `<` symbol but I think you dont need it as you are dealing with `cancel` and `done`.

Its working now. Hope this will work for you too !

Comment: I see no difference. The method was being called, and continues to do so. But the navigation back button title still remains the same. Am I missing something?

Comment: check value of `formHasChanged`. Better print it inside function.

Comment: As I've mentioned in my question, that output is correct. I've updated the question to contain the output. The method gets called, `formHasChanged` contains the right value. It's just that the navigation bar doesn't update.

Comment: Thanks for the persistence! One tiny thing that would be immensely useful - how would you add the `<` symbol back?

Comment: may be like `title: formHasChanged ? "< Cancel" : "< Back",` :P